# How to add second user control in panel by button click in first user control

Tags: c#

I have a **winform** and a **panel** on it and I am loading a user control (which is **first user control**) into the panel at runtime and my problem is how to add **second user control** in the same panel through button click in  ***first user control*** . I just like to simply go for the next user control by clicking the next button located in first user control.

Comment: What control are you trying to create in button click? Be specific for the answer to be good and helpful.

Comment: Im trying to add second user control in a panel by clicking button in first user control

Comment: When you say: user control, do you mean a control you've created or a control you drag onto the design surface (form) from the toolbar in visual studio?

Comment: If you're dragging a control to your form, @TerribleDog's answer should work for you. Just change the 'new Button()' type to your control type. You'll want to address the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create a button using a button, this might help. But please, be clear on what you are asking.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button newButton = new Button();
    //insert control properties here
    this.Controls.Add(newButton);  
}
```